# Vertx break out of a hung thread

Tags: java, multithreading, vert.x, vertx-verticle

So, the situation is like this: vert.x backend app has a worker Verticle instance that invokes a static method from Service class that in turn invoke a method from a 3rd Java lib that makes some requests and returns the result.

The problem arises in a specific situation where the 3rd party lib call hangs. The app gets stuck indefinitely at

```
java.base@11.0.8/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
```

and the vert.x `BlockedThreadChecker` starts throwing out warnings:

```
WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-worker-thread-18,5,main]=Thread[vert.x-worker-thread-18,5,main] has been blocked for 61537 ms, time limit is 60000 ms
```

and the verticle is left unresponsive.

I was looking for a solution of this issue. Changing the whole 3rd party lib would probably be an option if there was an alternative or time. Worker verticle (which I'm already using) and `executeBlocking` are not the solution because this is an infinitely blocking operation. I tried recognizing the hang with the separate watchdog verticle and redeploying it; this helped in a way that verticle was useful again but thread checker was still giving out warnings about the Thread blocked.

The best solution I have come so far is to let a watchdog recognize a hang and do a restart of the whole app, but that seems a bit radical and I would prefer to do it without shutting the app down, if possible. Is there an option I have overlooked?

Thank you in advance for advice.

Comment: This is, in fact, a difficult problem to solve, since threads in JVM in general are cooperative.